# How to work with Windows/Unix EOF warnings in binary data?

Tags: c, windows, unix, output, cmp

I was doing `cmp -l file.bin file2.bin` but started to get *cmp: EOF on file* and suspected Windows/Linux line-ending problem as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28950382/54964). 
I should be splitting binary data by some sequence so I did some profiling.
I noticed that this problem is about only some of my files which are of size 1GB.

Output from `od -c file.bin`

```
0435500  \n   <A5>  \n   Y  \n   f  \n   p  \n   <A9>  \n   A  \n   W  \n 202
0435520  \n   <B0>  \n   M  \n   t  \n 202  \n   <B1>  \n   i  \n   i  \n 227
0435540  \n 221  \n   Y  \n   ;  \n   <B2>  \n 225  \n   <  \n   J  \n 217
0435560  \n   <A9>  \n   <  \n 211  \n   <AB>  \n 201  \n   T  \n   y  \n 204
0435600  \n 212  \n   \  \n   v  \n   p  \n   |  \n   9  \n   M  \n   u
0435620  \n 214  \n   <  \n   r  \n   <A0>  \n   <AF>  \n   X  \n   W  \n 204
0435640  \n   <A5>  \n   B  \n   a  \n 207  \n   <AA>  \n   S  \n   ^  \n   |
0435660 004  \r  \n   > 003   <ED> 003   <E8>  \f   . 003   <EC>  \f   * 004 032
0435700  \f   h  \f   m  \f   i  \f   h  \n   o 004 024  \n   k  \n   <A5>
0435720  \n   <A2>  \n   =  \n   k  \n   p  \n   <B1>  \n   I  \n   ^  \n   y
0435740  \n 227  \n   <  \n   T  \n   |  \n 224  \n   8  \n   w  \n 202
```

where you see one output of `\r \n` in line 0435660.
In total, `11 matches on 11 lines` when total lines of 60 characters is 0571520. 
So there seems to be Windows line-endings 0.001% of file content which is significantly smaller than in normal cases. 
Only, the minority of files have this problem, and the original data sources do not. 
This suggests me that this is a problem in data processing. 
Is this enough confirmation that those endings are Windows line-endings?

My files contains events which should have fixed length each. 
So I am not sure how well `dos2unix` will work here, since I cannot change the length of the event.
I think I need to remove those events which have Windows line-endings or replace the windows EOF `\r\n` by `\0\n`. 
However, I am not sure if I can do this by adding the literal string into the content without changing the length of some events. 
The situation is if I change the length of some events, the system stops working.

How to work with Windows/Unix EOF warnings in binary data?

Comment: In binary files there are no line-endings, binary data is binary data. Some `\r\n` combinations might be part of longer binary sequences, it might just happen that there is a `0x0d` and a `0x0a` following each other in some places.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Why does `cmp -l` give such a warning sometimes? How to compare better binary data?

Comment: You have to think about the data that is actually stored in the files. We can't really tell what is the best way to compare, besides the `cmp` command, since we don't really know the data or the format. There may be embedded texts in the files, with or without newlines, we don't know.

Comment: And if you want data to be portable between platforms, the best way now (and has been for a long time, and will be for a foreseeable future) is plain ASCII text files., or optionally UTF-8 if you need more than the basic 127 characters in the ASCII character set.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Ever so minor a point: Why 127 in [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) vs 128?

Comment: cmp -l gives the warning EOF message if one file is shorter than the other.   Do you expect the files to be the same length?  Are both files of the length expected?

Comment: @chux Oops, that's true, 128 characters, from 0 to 127... :)

Comment: @chux Both files are not expected to be of the same length. So this is the reason of the error?

Comment: See [cmp (Unix)  -l, --verbose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cmp_(Unix))

Comment: @chux Thank you! This is not documented fully in standard GNU, BSD manuals. It seems that even wikipedia has newer manuals than in my current system.

Comment: I don't know about BSD, but it is fully documented in GNU -- just not in the man page. See my answer for details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `cmp` command prints a message:

`cmp: EOF on` ***SHORTER-FILE***

if one file is a *prefix* of the other, i.e., if one file is shorter than the other *and* the shorter file is identical to the beginning of the longer file.

If the two files are of different lengths but the shorter file is not a prefix of the longer one, `cmp` will report the first byte offset at which they differ, without an EOF warning.

On my system, the `cmp(1)` man page doesn't mention this, but it refers to the full documentation, which does.

If the GNU `diffutils` info documentation is not installed, or is configured incorrectly, the `info` command falls back to showing the man page.

On CentOS 5.11 (essentially identical to Red Hat), `info diff` shows the `diffutils` documentation; navigating to "Invoking cmp" shows the documentation for the `cmp` command. But it's an older version of the documentation, which is missing the information about the EOF message. (The diffutils 2.8.1 manual doesn't mention the EOF message; the diffutils 3.3 manual does.) Examining the history in the [git repo](http://savannah.gnu.org/git/?group=diffutils), the wording was added in 2002 and first included in release 2.8.2. To see which version of GNU `cmp` you're running, type `cmp --version`. (The behavior was there all along; the documentation was updated to reflect it.)

The [OSX `cmp(1)` man page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/cmp.1.html) is also the GNU diffutils version; it refers to the `info` documentation, but it also appears to be for version 2.8.1, which doesn't mention the EOF message.

Documentation for the current GNU diffutils version: http://www.gnu.org/software/diffutils/manual/html_node/Invoking-cmp.html

POSIX requires the same behavior: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cmp.html

Comment: Yes, the full documentation GNU and BSD does not have mentioning of EOF. At least not in those two manuals and not in my GNU/BSD manuals. It is only in that wikipage which source is some Physics department. POSIX manual is implicitly mentioning EOF but not so clearly as wiki.

Comment: @Masi: As I said, the *man page* doesn't, but the full GNU documentation does. I linked to it in my answer; you should also be able to see it on your system by typing `info cmp`.

Comment: Yes, I pasted what I see to the comment of chux's answer. My info cmp > its options is incomplete. No EOF mentioning in BSD and Redhat Linux variant. Actually, you should read `info diff`, not `info cmp` since it is incomplete.

Comment: @Masi: If the `info` documentation isn't installed, the `info` command falls back to the man page. On a CentOS 5.11 system, `info cmp` shows the man page; `info diff` shows the `diffutils` documentation, which includes the `cmp` documentation. But it's an older version with incomplete information on `cmp`. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Likely the reason for *cmp: EOF on file* is that files are of different length.

> -l, --verbose
>   Output the (decimal) byte numbers and (octal) values of all differing bytes, instead of the default standard output. Also, output the EOF message if one file is shorter than the other.  [ref](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cmp_(Unix))

Comment: The last line of Wikipage is missing in GNU and BSD manuals in `man`. I opened a new thread about getting better manuals in OSX here http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/194469/15504 but same problem is also in my Redhat Linux variant.

Comment: @Masi: The man page doesn't include this information, but it points to the version of the manual that does (for systems that use the GNU diffutils version of `cmp`): "The full documentation for `cmp` is maintained as a Texinfo manual.  If the `info` and `cmp` programs are properly installed  at  your site, the command `info cmp` should give you access to the complete manual."

Comment: @Masi  [@Keith Thompson](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31225273/2410359) is the better answer - suggest changing the accepted answer.

Comment: @chux In `info cmp`, I also see the `-l` flag without EOF mentioning. Also in Redhat variant. In reading info more, only `-l' --verbose' Print the (decimal) byte numbers and (octal) values of all differing bytes.`.

Comment: @chux: Older versions of the GNU `info` manual for `cmp` also omit the EOF message. See my updated answer for details.

Answer (score 0):

Read manuals in

```
info diff
```

and browse to the cmp sections. 
However, still incomplete manuals in GNU and BSD in OSX 10.10.3 and Redhat Linux variant.